# How to Save OnClickListener state

Tags: android, onclick, savestate

Okay so i have a program that requires the user to click the button to continue throughout the program. Every time the button is clicked the user is moved to a different stage in the program. The problem is i dont have a way or dont know a way i could possibly store where the user left off when the acitivty is destroyed. If anyone has any ideas please share them with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist data even after you app/activity is destroyed look into this example from google [sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/PersistentState.html). Another option is onSaveInstanceState(...) & onRestoreInstanceState(...)